# Can I publish plots for already derived and plotted data with different values?

Tags: publications, physics

I am doing MS Physics. If I take some previously derived results and plot them for different values, can I publish this work? If I do so, will it be like a review work? The plots are already there in the literature but I am going to take my own values e.g. I change the angle or the amplitude to see what happens and compare these with some other data to draw conclusions. I am totally new to publishing papers so kindly overlook my naivety.

Comment: What do you mean by "change values"? How? Sorry, but the question isn't clear.

Comment: @Buffy It  means I change certain parameters in the equations. For example I can change the angle for a certain experiment.

Comment: I wonder if any publisher would be interested, based on perceived lack of novelty. It is hard to judge the validity without knowing more about what you've done, but you would need to convince reviewers that it is "new" enough to warrant publication.

Comment: @Buffy Thank you:)

Comment: A lot depends on what the new conclusions you draw are. Hopefully you have a master's advisor to discuss such details with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would not be sufficient.  You need to present new information.  For example, if you show a well-known equation breaks down in an important scenario, and such a breakdown has never been documented, then that constitutes new info.